# How to fix 'No authentication methods available' when I use fabric==2.4.0 'sudo helper getpass.getpass'

Tags: python, fabric

when i useing python fabric moduls, Follow the tutorial:Click [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html)  .to connect remote hosts,and execute shell command, but the an error occured：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in sudo
  File "/root/tempFabric/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 29, in opens
    self.open()
  File "/root/tempFabric/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 615, in open
    self.client.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/root/tempFabric/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 437, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/root/tempFabric/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 750, in _auth
    raise SSHException("No authentication methods available")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available
```

```
$ import getpass
$ from fabric import Connection, Config
$ sudo_pass = getpass.getpass("123456")
123456
$ config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': sudo_pass}})
$ c=Connection(host='192.168.0.156',user='ai',port=22,config=config)
$ c.sudo('whoami', hide='stderr')
```

I expect the output of `c.sudo('whoami', hide='stderr')` to be :

```
ai
<Result cmd="...whoami" exited=0>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from fabric import Connection
result = Connection('web1', user='hello', connect_kwargs={
    "password": "123456",
    }, port=22).run('uname -s', hide=True)
msg = "Ran {0.command!r} on {0.connection.host}, got stdout:\n{0.stdout}"
print(msg.format(result))
```